# How to receive inputs from multiple users in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I want to design a page where multiple users will rank their favorite restaurants (out of 4 option) with their smartphone at the same time.
For example, if there are 3 users, the webpage should receive and stores the ranking result of all 3 users in variables.

How could I do this? Is Javascript a right choice?
I am very new to web development (but I have programming background), and I just need this for hi-fi prototyping.

Comment: As JS is the only language that runs on all browsers (wasm aside) ... I'd say yes, JS is the right choice.

Comment: You should add your source to question

Comment: Your question is far too broad and opinion based. SO is not the platform to ask for this type of question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @JonasWilms HTML and CSS are also browser languages that run in all browsers

Comment: @spflee if you want maintain an accumulation of rankings, more than likely you will need to perform some server side coding and use some sort of data store.  What you do in the front end matters less than the back end.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the details!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is a great choice for web apps, however keep in mind that if you want to use it in the smartphone outside of the browser it takes a bit more of effort (PWA).

You can achieve the functionality you are looking for with vanilla Javascript and some AJAX to communicate with a server to serve the restaurants info and to store the ranking info. You should store it in a database or a file because in variables they won't persist for too long.

If you really want to make this experience worth and usefull for your next projects I would suggest that you use some Javascript framework like VueJS that is very beginner-friendly, has a great documentation and a lot of examples out there. This part is called the fron-end and consists on the user interface that you will serve to your users. You should focus on building a responsive layout so that makes the experience in the smartphone better.

The back-end of the app is basically the server where you send the requests that feed info to your front-end. NodeJS is a good option because allows you to code in Javascript and it has a lot of examples and documentation avaiable too. For an easy start off you can also use ExpressJS to help with the implementation of your web server on NodeJS. As I said before you should use a database to persist the data, you can use MongoDB that allows for a great integration with the options I just gave you.

You can look for MEVN stack (Mongo, Express, Vue, Node) to have a better picture on how all of these technologies interact together.

What you want can be built in several ways with several technologies. If you are looking to keep it Javascript only this is a good option and it works great for me.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @Bruno Tavares. Really appreciate this detailed answer that clarify some doubt!